# What indemnities will I get if my company is declared bankrupt during a professionnalization contract?

Tags: employment, france, bankruptcy

I have a professionalization contract (*"Contrat de professionnalisation"*) in a determined duration (*"CDD"*) with a company that will soon be declared bankrupt in France. I find much information about this situation with an apprenticeship contract (*"Contrat d'apprentissage"*) saying that they get indemnities equal to the salaries they would have perceived until the end of the contract. Is it the same with a professionalization contract?

Comment: If I understand it right, a CDD is like... an apprenticeship but for jobs that have no apprenticeship program (e.g. plumber)?

Comment: @Trish are you saying plumbers don’t do apprenticeships or do do apprenticeships. In my experience, plumbers are one of those trades which are almost always subject to apprenticeships.

Comment: @DaleM I am saying that I understand that the CDD would be akin to an apprenticeship, which is how you become a plumber, but that the job with the CDD does not have such a regulated apprenticeship.

Comment: @Trish that's what I thought, but the plumber example comes right after the "no apprenticeship" part of your comment so its ambiguous.